# FAT16 on a USB drive with Mac OS 9?

Tags: mac, usb, external-disk, classic-mac-os

I can read a USB disk formatted as FAT32 on my PowerBook G4 with Mac OS 9.2.2 but it does not recognize and asks then I erase the disk if I insert one that is formatted as FAT16; formatting it as FAT32.

I can read a FAT16 floppy disk just fine using a USB-FDD.

Is it possible to add support for FAT formatted USB drives to Mac OS 9.2.2?

Comment: All versions of FAT (FAT, FAT32, exFAT) are fully supported on Mac OS 9.x. I have found that often it is best to format/partition the USB storage device on the Mac. You will generally have better results that way. I've never figured out **why** that is but it seems to give better results. It seems to vary between manufacturers but I have no empirical evidence but in my experience it *seems* that way.